# How to completely kill the activity? clear all

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyTimer();
}

//Таймер заставки в 3 секунды.
private void MyTimer() {
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int t = 3;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (t == 0) {
                timer.cancel();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Authors.class));
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain)).setImageDrawable(null);
                        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain)).destroyDrawingCache();
                    }
                });
            }
            t--;
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

in the book, the finish does not free memory from the pictures.

The picture is large, it is necessary to clean it.

Check through the IDEA Intelljj in "memory monitor".

size is different :

1. run, of memory size 21mb
2. run, of memory size 28mb
3. run, of memory size 28mb
4. run, of memory size 21mb
5. run, of memory size 21mb

run one activity

Why is this happening?
And how to completely kill the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are leaking the `Activity`. The anonymous inner `Runnable` will hold a strong reference of your `Activity` until all `Timers` are processed. In turn, the `MessageQueue` (an Android class) will hold a reference of your `Runnable` until it is processed.

Check out this [post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) for more information.

Comment: I called timer.cancel();
but all the same sizes randomly

Comment: ,My mistake is that I use the image in style. As it can clear ,  it is used only on one aktiviti